# Create csv file and download it in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I'm using Android Studio for a project and i have a problem.
I have a list of item, and if i click to a button for each item i called "downloadCsvFile" function and i pass the item.
I want that this function create a csv file and write the item data in it, and then download the file on the device.
How can i do it?
Thanks! :)

```
findViewById(R.id.buttonCsv).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                for (Item i: items) {
                    downloadCsvFile(i);
                }
            }

});
```